# How can we fetch all rows of a table in an array?

Tags: php, pdo

How can we fetch all rows of a table in an array? 
This table is not connected via php PDO
so far Ive tried the following returns last row of the resultset.

```
    $sth = $dbh->query("show tables;"); //select
    $sth->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

    $results= $sth->fetch();

    print_r($results);
```

Comment: To access data stored in rows you would use the DQL command `SELECT`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [fetchAll](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetchall.php)

```
$sth = $dbh->query("show tables;"); //select
$sth->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
$results= $sth->fetchAll();

var_dump($results);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$sth = $dbh->query("SELECT * FROM information_schema.TABLES WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = 'nameOfYourDb'"); 

while($row = $sth->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    print_r($row);
}

print_r($results);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$sth = $dbh->query("SELECT * FROM schema.TABLES WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = 'dbname'"); 
while ($row = $sth->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
    print_r($row);
}
```